# A tool for formatting .csproj files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, csproj, xml-formatting

Is there an option in Visual Studio or a tool (a plugin for VS?) to automatically format `.csproj` files if they get messed up after eg. a merge conflict resolution? Preferably format them the same way as Visual Studio does when it creates them. Maybe there is an option for that in ReSharper that I don't know about?

I have tried the command-line tool `organize-csproj` but it has a range of inconveniences - requires .NET Core 3.1 runtime installed, adds comments to the output `.csproj`, adds an XML declaration at the top and does not insert extra line breaks after each main element (after PropertyGroup or ItemGroup) like VS does. Its configuration doesn't seem to let me change that behavior either.

Comment: Wondering why you're so bothered about the formatting of an XML file that is not meant to be human readable. Fair enough if the project is failing to load though.

Comment: @phuzi I personally edit .csproj files manually very often. In many situations (particularly when you have many projects, and global settings from `Directory.Build.props` files, VS will mess stuff up if you use the property sheets.

Answer (score 1):

You can specifiy formatting options (e.g. identation) as for other files in the `.editorconfig` file. VS will normaly obey those rules. E.g., I have

```
[*.{csproj}]
charset = utf-8-bom
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
tab_width = 2
```

(as opposed to .cs files, where `indent_size` is typically 4)

Comment: But I presume this is for when a *new* project is created. Can this be applied to a `csproj` file which has been messed up?

Comment: That's correct. But it will help you to not mess it up manually. I haven't tried whether "format code" works on such a file, though.

Comment: Can this prevent messing up after a Git merge? "Format code" works but only in the basic way where it just prettifies the XML code. It doesn't reorganize elements if they get messed up.

Comment: No, that won't work. But a messed up merge can't be fixed by an editor, neither for project files nor for a source file. A messed up merge can leave the code in a _semantically_ incorrect state, which no automated process can fix.

Comment: Yes, but it is possible to have a messed up `csproj` which is still semantically correct but is still possible to reorganize for consistency. Eg. after a merge you could end up with several `ItemGroup`s containing `Reference`s while they all can be put into one `ItemGroup`. Also, VS first saves `PropertyGroup` and then all `ItemGroup`s. This could get rearranged after a merge and I'd like it get corrected too.

Answer (score 0):

You can beautify any XML file on XML level with the following method:

```
static void XmlFormat(string inFileName, string outFileName, 
                    bool _NewLineOnAttributes, 
                    string _IndentChars, 
                    bool _OmitXmlDeclaration)
{
    try
    {  
        //  adjust Encoding, if necessary
        TextReader rd = new StreamReader(inFileName, Encoding.Default);

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(rd);

        if (rd != Console.In)
        {
            rd.Close();
        }

        //  adjust Encoding if necessary
        var wr = new StreamWriter(outFileName, false, Encoding.Default);

        //  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwritersettings?view=net-5.0
        var settings =
            new XmlWriterSettings 
            { 
                Indent = true, 
                IndentChars = _IndentChars,
                NewLineOnAttributes = _NewLineOnAttributes,
                OmitXmlDeclaration = _OmitXmlDeclaration
            };

        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(wr, settings))
        {
            doc.WriteContentTo(writer);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error formatting {inFileName}: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe this will do more or less the same thing as the `Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D` in VS will for a `csproj` file.